# Fedora 23: installation on virtual box windows 10 host

Tags: fedora, gnome, virtualbox

I am trying to install Fedora 23 on VirtualBox running on Windows 10 host. I am using `Fedora-Live-Workstation-x86_64-23-10.iso` to install.

**Configuration Selected:**

- RAM allocated: 4096 MB
- HDD allocated: 64 GB, Fixed
- Processors allocated: 2, PAE/NX selected
- Display memory allocated: 128 MB (full)
- 3D Acceleration: Enabled
- OS Selected: Fedora 23 64-bit
- VirtualBox version: 4.3

**Host machine Configuration**

- Intel i3-4150@3.5GHz, 8GB RAM, 500GB HDD, Onboard Intel graphics

**Problem:** During installation it shows the screen where you have to select between `Install to hard drive` and `start fedora`. Right at that screen I get **Oh no! Something has gone wrong** message. Even if I exhibit lightning reflexes and select any of the options, this error is the end result.

I can press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F2` to launch a terminal. But again I am clueless here.

P.S.: Sometimes, only *some* time, a smaller frame overlaps this message. This frame is like a peep hole to installation process. Lot of scrolling in all directions helps install Fedora, but this error appears on reboot.

What other information can I provide?

**EDIT 1:**

The same configuration works flawlessly on a colleague's computer. Only he has alloted **12** MB as video memory without acceleration of any kind. I made those same changes with no effect.

**EDIT 2:**
My colleague is running his virtualbox on Windows 8.1 (Mine is Windows 10). I believe this may be a cause of the said error.

Comment: Try using the Basic Graphics installation option and see if the issue is still there.

Comment: You can also hit `Ctrl+L` in the "Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager" to see the log files. Maybe there is something useful logged.

Comment: @schaiba I do not see such an option.

Comment: Also turn off PAE option

Comment: Done. Still the same...

Comment: ran `sudo dnf remove gdm*`. Boots to terminal now...

Comment: Is that the intel virtualization technology is enabled in the bios setting?

Comment: Do you have up-to-date Virtualbox?

Comment: My bet is that you need to enable virtualization technology on your BIOS as already said by @GAD3R

Comment: Grub menu -> Troubleshooting (if memory serves), that's where the Basic graphics mode is.

Comment: Installed `xfce`. Boots to XFCE desktop. Battling with VBoxAdditions now...

Comment: @GAD3R, yes it is.

Comment: @Jakuje: Its 4.3.28. version 5 has known compatibility issues

Comment: when you see the message " OH.." hit ctrl+alt+f4 login as root and uninstall libinput using `dnf remove xorg-x11-drv-libinput` then `killall -u liveuser` and `logout` . Log in again and type `startx`

Comment: @GAD3R, Looks like gnome desktop was creating problems. So I removed gdm and installed xfce, as mentioned in a previous comment. Now I can boot to desktop and I do not see that error.

Answer (score 0):

Well, some digging revealed that my version of Windows 10 was not compatible with virtualbox and fedora's GDM.

**Steps taken**:

1. Press `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`F2`
2. Enter your username
3. Enter the password

The below commands are to be run on the terminal

1. Remove GDM (gnome desktop manager) entirely. Command `sudo dnf remove gdm*`
2. Install XFCE or some such (anything except the friggin' Gnome. `sudo dnf install xfce`

Not marking as a solution, since it's only a workaround. Or maybe, to rack up some points, I might mark it as one later.